# How can I use the same properties and methods on different classes?

Tags: c#, class, object, conditional-statements, construction

I have 3 class like ClassVersion1, ClassVersion2 and ClassVariables. ClassVariables is for reach variables of other class from Form.

İn my opinion were these;

```
if(version == 1)
{
    ClassVersion1 clss = new ClassVersion1();
}
else
{
    ClassVersion2 clss = new ClassVersion2();
}
clss.vars.variable1 = 3;
clss.vars.variable2=5;
clss.DoSomething();
```

But I have to call functions and variabless into the if condition(two objects with same name, different class). I want to Create object into condition and use out of condition.

How can I do this?

Comment: You can use a BASE-CLASS or an Interface

Comment: Welcome to [SO]. please format the code in you question as you would in your source code: indentation makes code easier to read and understand; and thus your question easier to answer.

Answer (score 7):

You could use an interface:

```
public interface IVersionedClass
{
    int Variable1 { get; set; }
    string Variable2 { get; set; }
}


public class ClassVersion1 : IVersionedClass
{
    public int Variable1 { get; set; }
    public string Variable2 { get; set; }
}

public class ClassVersion2 : IVersionedClass
{
    public int Variable1 { get; set; }
    public string Variable2 { get; set; }
}
```

Then use it like this:

```
IVersionedClass myClass;
if(version == 1)
{
    myClass = new ClassVersion1();
}
else
{
    myClass = new ClassVersion2();
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot  @CodeCaster I did this but now, I have new problems. 1. The modifier 'public' is not valid.                                2. A property, indexer or dynamic member access may not be passed as an out or ref parameter.  ?????

Comment: Those errors do not arise from the code I posted. Interface members don't have `public` modifiers, don't know how you got the second error.